# How to get array of all values of a specific field in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have such schema in mongoDB

```
{
    "key":"ru",
    "regions":[
        {
            "name":"moskovskaya",
            "cities":[
                {
                    "name":"moskva"
                },
                {
                    "name":"tula"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"piterskaya",
            "cities":[
                {
                    "name":"piter"
                },
                {
                    "name":"luga"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i have some documents of such schema for different countries,
how can i get an array of ALL cities from each document of this schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following aggregation pipeline :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$regions" },
    { "$unwind": "$regions.cities" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "cities": { "$push": "$regions.cities.name" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "cities" : [ 
                "moskva", 
                "tula", 
                "piter", 
                "luga"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are pro))

Answer (score 8):

This is a straightforward query. The [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method will  beautifully get the job done.

```
db.collection.distinct("regions.cities.name")
```

which produces:

```
[ "luga", "moskva", "piter", "tula" ]
```