# Distinct array element with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "tags": [ 
        { "code": "01-01", "type": "machine" },
        { "code": "04-06", "type": "gearbox" },
        { "code": "07-01", "type": "machine" } 
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "tags": [
        { "code": "03-04","type": "gearbox" },
        { "code": "01-01", "type": "machine" },
        { "code": "04-11", "type": "machine" }
    ]
}
```

I want to get distinct codes only for tags whose type is "machine". so, for the example above, the result should be `["01-01", "07-01", "04-11"]`.
How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get array from mongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210121/how-to-get-array-from-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$unwind` and then `$group` with the tag as the key will give you each tag in a separate document in your result set:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            "tags.type": "machine" 
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tags.code"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id:false
            code: "$_id"
        }
    }
]);
```

Or, if you want them put into an array within a single document, you can use `$push` within a second `$group` stage:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            "tags.type": "machine" 
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tags.code"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: null,
            codes: {$push: "$_id"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Another user suggested including an initial stage of  `{ $match: { "tags.type": "machine" } }`.  This is a good idea if your data is likely to contain a significant number of documents that do not include **"machine"** tags.  That way you will eliminate unnecessary processing of those documents.  Your pipeline would look like this:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            "tags.type": "machine" 
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$tags"
    },
    {
        $match: { 
            "tags.type": "machine" 
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$tags.code"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: null,
            codes: {$push: "$_id"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to lead off with `{  $match: { "tags.type": "machine" } }` to get rid of any documents that won't contribute.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
> db.foo.aggregate( [
... { $unwind : "$tags" },
... { $match : { "tags.type" : "machine" } },
... { $group : { "_id" : "$tags.code" } },
... { $group : { _id : null , "codes" : {$push : "$_id"} }}
... ] )
{ "_id" : null, "codes" : [ "04-11", "07-01", "01-01" ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

**A better way** would be to group directly on *tags.type* and use **addToSet** on *tags.code*.

Here's how we can achieve the same output in 3 stages of aggregation :

```
db.name.aggregate([
  {$unwind:"$tags"},

  {$match:{"tags.type":"machine"}},

  {$group:{_id:"$tags.type","codes":{$addToSet:"$tags.code"}}} 
])
```

Output : { "_id" : "machine", "codes" : **[ "04-11", "07-01", "01-01" ]** }

Also, if you wish to filter out tag.type codes, we just need to replace "machine" in match stage with desired tag.type.