# Query to return flattened embedded fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been searching for an answer but can't find it anywhere.

When I use the following method in robomongo to retrieve an embedded field of documents matching a criteria, I get a list a all the matching documents.
All these documents contain an array of documents with my selected embedded field.

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
    { "bom.COMPONENT": "101-00001-017" },
    { _id: 0, "CicodeList.Cicode": 1 }
)
```

**Result**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "CicodeList" : [ 
        {
            "Cicode" : "one"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "CicodeList" : [ 
        {
            "Cicode" : "two"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "CicodeList" : [ 
        {
            "Cicode" : "three"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to get is a single array containing all the embedded fields of all documents, something like this:

```
{ results: ["one", "two", "three"] }
```

the original documents look a little like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583df12093181938d03c50eb"),
    "CicodeList" : [ 
        {
            "Cicode" : "one"
        }, 
        {
            "Cicode" : "two"
        }
    ],
    "bom" : [ 
        {
            "COMPONENT" : "101-00001-017"
        }, 
        {
            "COMPONENT" : "101-00008-002"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583df12193181938d03c50ec"),
    "CicodeList" : [ 
        {
            "Cicode" : "three"
        }, 
        {
            "Cicode" : "four"
        }
    ],
    "bom" : [ 
        {
            "COMPONENT" : "101-00001-017"
        }, 
        {
            "COMPONENT" : "101-00008-002"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've got to use the Aggregation Framework for that. Or just let your application code take care of it.

Comment: @wallage thanks for documents, I've updated my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get array from mongoDB collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210121/how-to-get-array-from-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following query that uses [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/aggregation/) framework

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { 
        $match : { "bom.COMPONENT": "101-00001-017" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$CicodeList"
        }
    }, 
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": null,
            "results": { $push: "$CicodeList.Cicode" } 
        }
    }
])
```

It will print out all existed values of Cicode for "bom.COMPONENT" equals "101-00001-017"

```
{"results" : [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ]}
```

Comment: does the aggregate have an advantage over the distinct method provided by "Chridam"?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run the **[`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#return-distinct-values-for-an-embedded-field)** method on the embedded field as follows

```
db.getCollection('test').distinct("CicodeList.Cicode",
    { "bom.COMPONENT": "101-00001-017" } /* query */
)
```

**Result**

```
/* 1 */
[
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
]
```

Comment: thanks for the support. it seems to work perfectly. what is the difference with the aggregate method provided by "Oleksandr"

Comment: The difference is distinct is a completely different command which returns an array of distinct values. Whilst the aggregation framework gives the same results, the process of `$unwind` can potentially bring performance down as it "produces a copy of each document per array entry" which uses more memory (possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory) and therefore also takes "time" to produce as well as "time" to process.